# Move branch to another point in history

Tags: git, branch

We have the following history

```
start         master  public
|                 |   |
v                 v   v
o---o-- ... --o---o---o
```

Unfortunately we made some commits into the `master` branch containing some sensitive data. We amended this in a separate branch called public. Now we want to "cut-off" the `public` branch in order get a complete and clean "state" in `public` but without the compromising history parts still contained via `master`. In other words we want the following new history:

```
start         master
|                 |
v                 v
o---o-- ... --o---o
 \
  o <- public
```

Now checking out `public` shall lead to the same working tree as in the original situation but without the sensible history details. Afterwards we mothball the old `master` branch: Rename it to `unsafe` and elaborate a new `master` branch out of the new `public` branch. This way we conserve the old history in `unsafe` and are able to push the `public` branch into the public without any worries:

```
start         unsafe
|                 |
v                 v
o---o-- ... --o---o
 \
  o---o-- ... --o <-- public
   \           /
    o-- .. --o-- ... --o <-- master
```

What are the right git commands to achieve this?

PS: Of course we could checkout `start`, make a new branch and commit there the entire working tree of the `public` branch. But there must be a different, fancier, git way!

Comment: @phlipsy this isn't actually off topic on SU, but I'll migrate this to SO as requested, so that you don't have to repost.

Comment: This information might help: http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/ .

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to merge all commits in public into one commit (i.e. merging several commits to one, or removing individual commits entirely, etc.) is to use `git rebase -i`. So what you would do is (assuming the first commit has a tag `start` as your graph indicates):

```
git checkout public
git rebase -i start
```

An editor window comes up where you can edit the order of all the patches
simply use `squash` for all your patches. After you saved that file and closed the editor, `git` will recombine your patch history as requested. Of course, the master branch will not change its history at all.

To rename your current master as unsafe and start all further development on public, I would do:

```
git checkout -b unsafe master # <- creates a new branch "unsafe"
git checkout master
git reset --hard public    # <- forces master branch to point to public
```

If you don't create the `unsafe` branch, the hard reset will loose all commits in master and you won't be able to (easily) access them any more. So make sure you really created that branch.

An alternative would be to rename `master` to `unsafe` and then create a new master branch:

```
git branch -m master unsafe  # renames master to unsafe
git checkout -b master public  # creates new branch master as a copy of public
```

Both should result in the exact same branch structure. (Granted, the second does not have that danger of loosing the history...)

Comment: I had to fiddle around a bit because you can't squash all commits (which one will remain?). But finally it worked for me. Thank you, that's the solution!

Comment: I tried it on our real life project and: Wow! This was the craziest rebase I ever did in my entire life! Be prepared to get in touch with all your merging conflicts of the whole history of your project.